# How to set a swiper slider to start from right, rather than left?

Tags: jquery, slide, swiper.js

I want to have 2 Swiper sliders staying side by side, one starting from left, the other one from right, How to set one of them to start from right going to left?

[image]

`<- [a...] [a3] [a2] [a1]` || `[b1] [b2] [b3] [b...] ->`

For example each swiper has 12 slides.
I tried `RTL` and many other approaches but none of them works for me. `RTL` puts an empty space at the beginning.

Thanks for any kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are probably looking for the ***initialSlide*** parameter. Setting it to your last slide index and it will give you what you want (if I understood it well!)